# what does engaged mean?

Tags: meaning

> An **engaged**, informed workforce is a big competitive differentiator in today’s service economy. However, conventional intranets—even those with the latest search technologies and social 1.0 features—aren’t delivering a competitive advantage. Most employees still struggle to find information and experts, and nearly 70% remain **unengaged**.2

I have problem in the meaning of unengaged here. it means some one that is doing work? and so  unengaged  means not do work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [***engage***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/engage):

> 5. to draw into; involve"   ⇒ *to engage him in conversation*"

In this case meaning the employees are (or aren't) actively involved and participating in the goals of the company.